# Create temp table with variable on Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, variables, temp-tables

I am trying to create a temp table on Microsoft SQL Server 2014 using a variable.

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(50)
SET @TableName = 'MyShema.MyTable'

EXEC('SELECT * INTO #temp FROM ' + @TableName)
SELECT * FROM #temp
```

However, the last line, `SELECT * FROM #temp` gives `Invalid object name '#temp.` Can anyone please tell me how I can fix it? Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: There is a mapping table that contains source file names and destination tables for bulkinsert. Before bulkinsert, some data clean up in a temp table is necessary. So I am just trying to loop through this mapping list and set `@TableName` and create a temp table one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TableName1 VARCHAR(50)

SET @TableName1 = 'dbo.encounter'

EXEC('SELECT * INTO ##temp FROM ' + @TableName1)

SELECT * FROM ##temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link.

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_table

The temp table created in a dynamic SQL statement is dropped at the 
exit of that statement. That is why you got the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @sql = N'SELECT * INTO #temp FROM from MyShema.MyTable ; SELECT * FROM #tmpA';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: This gives the same error `Invalid object name '#tmp'` Would you advice how can i use a variable `@TableName` to perform the task?

Comment: There is a typo in the string. You cannot see the table #tmpA when you SELECT INTO #temp.

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.